# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to type 'System.Linq.IGrouping

Tags: c#

I am currently getting the following error during runtime and not compile time and not sure what the problem is

The error I am getting is on this line in the GetAllocationsViewModel method

```
var allocationsGrouped = Mapper.Map<ILookup<string,FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION>, ILookup<string,FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>>(GetAllocationsGrouped(EntityType.Firm, firm.ID, d));
```

> InnerException {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[BSG.Manager.WebUI.ViewModels.Allocations.FirmWideAllocationsViewModel]' to type 'System.Linq.IGrouping2[BSG.Manager.WebUI.ViewModels.Allocations.FirmWideAllocationsViewModel]'."}
>   System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

Not sure why it says Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List as I am returning ILookup. At compile time there seems to be no problem. Is it got to do with AutoMapper

Code

```
private AllocationsViewModel GetAllocationsViewModel(int id, DateTime date)
{

    var ms = GetStrategy(id);

    DateTime d = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    if (ms.FIRM_ID != null)
    {
        var firm = GetService<FIRM>().Get(ms.FIRM_ID.Value);
        var currentEntity = new EntityAllocationsViewModel(new EntityViewModel { EntityId = firm.ID, EntityName = firm.NAME, EntityType = EntityType.Firm });
        //var allocationsGrouped = Mapper.Map<List<FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION>, List<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>>(GetAllocationsGrouped(EntityType.Firm, firm.ID, d).ToList());

        var allocationsGrouped = Mapper.Map<ILookup<string,FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION>, ILookup<string,FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>>(GetAllocationsGrouped(EntityType.Firm, firm.ID, d));


        var vm = new AllocationsViewModel
        {
            CurrentEntity = currentEntity,
            //ManagerAllocations = allocationsGrouped,
         //   MissingProducts = missingProducts
        };

        return vm;
    }

    return null;
}   

protected ILookup<string, FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION> GetAllocationsGrouped(EntityType entity, int id, DateTime date)
{
    _logger.Info($"GetAllocationsGrouped entity:{entity} id:{id} date:{date}");
    var allocations = IoC.Resolve<IPackageRepo>().GetManagerAllocationsGrouped(entity, id, date);
    return  allocations;
}

ILookup<string, FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION> IPackageRepo.GetManagerAllocationsGrouped(EntityType entity, int id, DateTime date, int? count)
{
    var allocations = GetManagerAllocations(entity, id, date);

    var allocationsLookup  = allocations.ToLookup(a => a.MANAGER_STRATEGY_NAME, a => a);

    // add grouping by entity
    var allocationsGrouped = GroupManagerAllocationsByEntity(entity, allocations);

    var strategyTotals = allocationsGrouped.GroupBy(mgrStrat => new { mgrStrat.MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID }).Select(s => new { MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID = s.Key.MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID, StrategyTotal = s.Sum(x => x.UsdEmv) }).ToDictionary(k => k.MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID, v => v.StrategyTotal);

    var sum = allocationsGrouped.Sum(a => a.EMV);


    foreach (IGrouping<string, FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION> item in allocationsLookup)
    {

        var allocationsGroup = item.Select(a => a);

        foreach (var alloc in allocationsGroup)
        {
            if (sum > 0 && strategyTotals[alloc.MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID] != 0)
            {
                alloc.Percent = alloc.EMV / sum;
                alloc.GroupPercent = alloc.EMV / strategyTotals[alloc.MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID];

            }
        }
    }

    return allocationsLookup;
}
```

Automapper code

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    Mapper.Initialize((config) =>
    {
       config.ReplaceMemberName("FIRM_ID", "FirmID");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("FIRM_NAME", "FirmName");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID", "ManagerStrategyID");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("MANAGER_STRATEGY_NAME", "ManagerStrategyName");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_ID", "ManagerAccountClassID");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_NAME", "ManagerAccountingClassName");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("MANAGER_FUND_ID", "ManagerFundID");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("MANAGER_FUND_NAME", "ManagerFundName");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("MANAGER_FUND_OR_CLASS_ID", "ManagerFundOrClassID");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("NAV", "Nav");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("PRODUCT_ID", "ProductID");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("PRODUCT_NAME", "ProductName");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("QUANTITY", "Quantity");
    config.ReplaceMemberName("EVAL_DATE", "EvalDate");
        config.CreateMap<FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION, FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>().ReverseMap();

    });
}
```

Models

```
public class FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION 
{
    private decimal _groupPercent;
    public int FIRM_ID { get; set; }        
    public string FIRM_NAME { get; set; }
    public int? MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID { get; set; }
    public int? MANAGER_FUND_ID { get; set; }
    public int MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_ID { get; set; }
    public int? MANAGER_FUND_OR_CLASS_ID { get; set; }
    public string MANAGER_FUND_NAME { get; set; }
    public string MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_NAME { get; set; }
    public string MANAGER_STRATEGY_NAME { get; set; }
    public int? PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_NAME { get; set; }

    public int? QUANTITY { get; set; }
    public decimal? NAV { get; set; }

    public DateTime EVAL_DATE { get; set; }
    public int? DEFAULT_STRATEGY_ID { get; set; }
    public string DEFAULT_STRATEGY_NAME { get; set; }
    public decimal USD_EMV { get; set; }

    //needed for kendo aggregates
    public decimal UsdEmv => USD_EMV;

    public decimal EMV { get; set; }
    public decimal WEIGHT { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal Percent { get; set; } // manual calc
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal Sort
    {
        get
        {
            return PRODUCT_NAME == "Other"
                ? decimal.MaxValue
                : USD_EMV;
        }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal GroupPercent
    {
        get { return _groupPercent; }
        set { _groupPercent = value; }
    }
} 

 public class FirmWideAllocationsViewModel
{
    public List<string> Hierarchy
    { get; set; }

    private decimal _groupPercent;
    public int FirmID { get; set; }
    public string FirmName { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerStrategyID { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerFundID { get; set; }
    public int ManagerAccountClassID{ get; set; }
    public int? ManagerFundOrClassID { get; set; }
    public string ManagerFundName { get; set; }
    public string ManagerAccountingClassName { get; set; }
    public string ManagerStrategyName { get; set; }
    public int? ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? Nav { get; set; }

    public DateTime EvalDate { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultStrategyID { get; set; }
    public string DEFAULT_STRATEGY_NAME { get; set; }
    public decimal Usd_Emv { get; set; }

    //needed for kendo aggregates
    public decimal UsdEmv => Usd_Emv;

    public decimal Emv { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal Percent { get; set; } // manual calc
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal Sort
    {
        get
        {
            return ProductName == "Other"
                ? decimal.MaxValue
                : Usd_Emv;
        }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal GroupPercent
    {
        get { return _groupPercent; }
        set { _groupPercent = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Awww, poor thing, try to convince your leader to get rid of AutoMapper. "_At compile time there seems to be no problem._" - of course, that's an AutoMapper artifact. And seeing that _all_ of the property names are different, a simple `ToViewModel` mapping method would be not just more simple and straightforward but would allow you to debug it and see all broken things at compile time. See also: https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/

Comment: AM doesn't know anything about ILookup. You need to tell AM how that can be mapped.